# Running dynamic web projects on Eclipse brings up a 404 error in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, build, http-status-code-404

I'm not entirely sure why this happens.

Right now I'm able to build the project without running into any issues, and it deploys to the eclipse tomcat server that I have running

[image: This is what my directory structure looks like.]

So with that kept in mind, the index here is hera.jsp, which I have set in my web.xml file:

[image: Web.xml file]

to make matters worse it seems like no matter what I try I always get this same error message:

[image: 404]

All I can think to include to make this more complete before posting is my build path and the server settings, so here's those as well.

[image: Server]
[image: Build path]

Comment: the screenshot shows a compilation error. to ensure proper deployment check the manager console for your WAR

Comment: Which screenshot is that?  I ask as the 3rd screenshot is the topic of this entire post.

Comment: screenshot for project structure shows a red cross at src. that one

Comment: It's bitching about a spelling error.

Comment: did you check the manager console to ensure deloyment

Comment: Not sure what that is.....I've always used netbeans to deploy web-projects and I've just recently switched, so any help you provide would be great.

Comment: start server and in browser type in http://localhost:8080/ [if 8080 is your port number]. you will get the welcome page. then look for manager or admin console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem. First of all:

1. Check if all the sources are copied to tomcat7 webapps, especially hera/WEB-INF/web.xml.
   If its not there, try to create dummy folder in your project, e.g. "hera/fix", and in your
   "project properties->deployment assembly" add this folder (as a result, "hera/fix -> /" mapping should be created). This worked for me when the eclipse plugin didn't want to copy web.xml.
2. Check in "project properties->deployment assembly" if all needed libraries are there, if not, add them.
3. Check why you have problems in src in your eclipse project, as that may interrupt or conflict the dynamic project deployment from eclipse.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer is right for the most part.  I got my stuff up and running once.... then Tomcat shit the bed again.  My solution is to install Jboss 7.1 and be done with it.